# Set TTS output to 16 or 8kHz

Tags: android, text-to-speech, sampling

as I route the TTS output to a bluetooth headset, it would be good have it in a 16 or 8kHz Sampling.
How do I achieve that? And is it actually possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sorry, this is not possible. You would need to modify the **TTS Class**. However, I tried it with `startBluetoothSco()` and it worked. Maybe you try it, too.

Comment: Yeah, I already tried it, and it works. Thanks for the answer though.